# gridview paging issue, argument out of range when going to previous page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, indexing, page-index-changed

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: value
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: value

Source Error:

Line 95:     protected void changed(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
Line 96:     {
Line 97:         GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
Line 98:         //GridView1.DataBind();
Line 99:     }


Source File: c:\Users\Sartaj\Desktop\web\Websites\Asp_website_projectv1\AddInventory.aspx.cs    Line: 97

Stack Trace:

[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: value]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.set_PageIndex(Int32 value) +1318287
   AddInventory.changed(Object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e) in c:\Users\Sartaj\Desktop\web\Websites\Asp_website_projectv1\AddInventory.aspx.cs:97
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnPageIndexChanging(GridViewPageEventArgs e) +133
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandlePage(Int32 newPage) +86
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +464
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +207
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +175
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565


My gridview is->
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True" AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
        BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="7" CellSpacing="5" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="1" OnPageIndexChanging="changed" >
                    <PagerSettings Mode="NextPrevious" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#999999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle ForeColor="#0033CC" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="Silver" ForeColor="White" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                </asp:GridView>

**my backend code is->**
protected void addInventoryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addInventoryAllSelectDataSource.InsertParameters[0].DefaultValue = imeiText.Text;
        addInventoryAllSelectDataSource.InsertParameters[1].DefaultValue = carrierDropDown.SelectedValue;
        addInventoryAllSelectDataSource.InsertParameters[2].DefaultValue = ((int)d1[modelDropDown.SelectedIndex][0]).ToString();
        addInventoryAllSelectDataSource.InsertParameters[3].DefaultValue = costPriceText.Text;
        addInventoryAllSelectDataSource.InsertParameters[4].DefaultValue = sellingPriceText.Text;
        addInventoryAllSelectDataSource.InsertParameters[5].DefaultValue = dateText.Text;
        addInventoryAllSelectDataSource.InsertParameters[6].DefaultValue = smartphoneRadioList.SelectedValue;
        addInventoryAllSelectDataSource.InsertParameters[7].DefaultValue = transferOrderNoText.Text;
        addInventoryAllSelectDataSource.InsertParameters[8].DefaultValue = Session["user"].ToString();
        addInventoryAllSelectDataSource.Insert();
       // gridList.Add(new AddImei(imeiText,carrierDropDown.SelectedValue,(((int)d1[modelDropDown.SelectedIndex][0]).ToString())
           // ,Convert.ToDouble(costPriceText.Text),Convert.ToDouble(sellingPriceText.Text),dateText.Text);
        //GridView1.DataSource = gridList;
        //GridView1.DataBind();
        //GridView1.DataSource = selectInventoryDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        //GridView1.DataBind();
        addInventoryAllSelectDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT A.IMEI,A.CARRIER, F.MAKE, F.MODEL, A.COST_PRICE,A.SELLING_PRICE,A.DATE,A.SMARTPHONE,A.TRANSFER_ORDER_NO,A.USER_ID FROM AddInventory AS A FULL OUTER JOIN "+carrierDropDown.SelectedValue+" AS F ON A.CARRIER_ID_INVENTORY = F.CARRIER_ID WHERE (A.IMEI = '"+imeiText.Text+"')";
        d3  = (DataView)addInventoryAllSelectDataSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        gridList.Add(new AddImei(d3[0][0].ToString(), d3[0][1].ToString(), d3[0][2].ToString(), d3[0][3].ToString(), Convert.ToDouble(d3[0][4]), Convert.ToDouble(d3[0][5]), Convert.ToDateTime(d3[0][6]).Date, Convert.ToBoolean(d3[0][7]), d3[0][8].ToString(), d3[0][9].ToString()));
        //AddImei ob1=new AddImei(d3[0][0].ToString(), d3[0][1].ToString(), d3[0][2].ToString(), d3[0][3].ToString(), Convert.ToDouble(d3[0][4]), Convert.ToDouble(d3[0][5]), Convert.ToDateTime(d3[0][6]).Date, Convert.ToBoolean(d3[0][7]), d3[0][8].ToString(), d3[0][9].ToString());
        GridView1.DataSource = gridList;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

The issue is that when i click next page, it does not change page, i click again then the page changes. After going to next page, i click on the previous page nothing changes, i click again and then i get the above exception. i have been looking to sort this issue for hours, cant figure out what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to call the function that fill the GridView1 after the PageIndexChanged Event

```
 protected void changed(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
 {
     GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
     this.fillGridView1();
 }
```

Comment: do i have to create the fillGridView1 method. ? there is none at the moment ?

Comment: Now its working, i followed your advice and created the fillGridView method.

protected void changed(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        this.fillGridView1();
        //GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    private void fillGridView1()
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = gridList;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        
    }   i just wanted to ask is this the best way to do it?

Comment: there are many ways to get the same results, but I used to do it that way.